# Расстояние между двумя точками на карте, заданными с помощью географических координат?

Tags: c, геометрия, objective-c, алгоритм

Доброго времени суток!

Есть две координаты, каждая с широтой/долготой типа double:
`double lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2`.

**Вопрос: как подсчитать расстояние в метрах между этими координатами?**

---

Я столкнулся с тем, что мне хотелось бы применить некоторые оптимизации для вычислений, связанных с большим количеством гео-точек на карте (алгоритмы для класстеризации), и для этого мне было бы хорошо разобраться в том, как считают расстояния соответствующие функции из Apple API, но так как их код скрыт, я решил попробовать разобраться с тем, как они считают расстояния, сам.

Буду благодарен за любую подсказку по поводу решения этой (наверное) простой задачи. Я уверен в том, что, конечно, разберусь с этим вопросом и без помощи ХК, просто надеюсь, вдруг кто-то из участников внесёт ясность блестящим и точным ответом)) Как всегда, подчёркиваю, что мне интересен ваш личный опыт, а не ссылки на то, что гуглится сверху: например, может быть вы знаете, как сделать этот подсчёт самым быстрым способом.

P.S. Также параллельно я только что открыл [топик на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241700/what-code-is-written-behind-cllocation-distancefromlocation-or-mkmetersbetwe) про те самые Apple API, вдруг кто оттуда подскажет, что скрывается в их чёрном ящике.

---

Добавлю немного контекста:

```
+ (NSArray *)sortArray:(NSArray *)array byDistanceToLocation:(CLLocation *)location {
    return [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D place1Coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[obj1 valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue], [[obj1 valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]);
        CLLocation *obj1location = [CLLocation locationWithCoordinate:place1Coordinate];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D place2Coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[obj2 valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue], [[obj2 valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]);
        CLLocation *obj2location = [CLLocation locationWithCoordinate:place2Coordinate];

        if ([location distanceFromLocation:obj1location] > [location distanceFromLocation:obj2location]) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        }

        if ([location distanceFromLocation:obj1location] < [location distanceFromLocation:obj2location]) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        }

        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }];
}
```

Приведённый метод сортирует массив с точками на основе расстояния между каждой из этих точек и данной точкой.

Возникла простая мысль: почему бы для возможного ускорения процесса вместо полновесного подсчёта расстояний с помощью `Apple API: -[CLLocation distanceFromLocation:]` не сравнивать между собой "неполные эвклидовы расстояния" (сумма квадратов без извлечения корня), подсчитанные для обычных географических координат (рассуждение очень похоже на то, которое провёл @aknew в комментарии): сравнивать `pow(lat1 - lat, 2) + pow(lng1 - lng, 2)` и `pow(lat2 - lat, 2) + pow(lng2 - lng, 2)`? Наивное размышление подсказывает, что вроде бы результат должен получаться тот же самый, если не забираться сильно к полюсам, но вот результаты получаются какие-то немного странные - "почти те", да не совсем - я встречаю места которые при повторном их измерении с помощью `distanceFromLocation:` стоят в обратном порядке: вроде "сначала 12км, а потом 11км" - то есть порядок сортировки нарушается. Отсюда и возникла мысль разобраться в том, что же стоит за `distanceFromLocation:`.

---

```
+ (NSArray *)sortArrayOfLocations3:(NSArray *)array byDistanceToLocation:(CLLocation *)location {
    for (EKALocation *_location in array) {
        _location->precalculatedDistanceToLocation = @([_location distanceFromLocation:location]);
    }

    return [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"precalculatedDistanceToLocation" ascending:YES]]];
}
```

Если интересно, почему ->, а не Objective-C @property, см. [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439623/when-where-the-arrow-notation-should-be-used-in-objective-c).

---

Спасибо.

Comment: А Вы хотите узнать как это реализовано именно в Apple API, или Вас устроит математический подход? [Формула гаверсинусов](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

Comment: а каков масштаб расстояний для этих точек? Не знаю как считает эппл, но для небольших расстояний я бы считал просто по теореме Пифагора считая что у нас прямоугольная сетка (градус же для конкретной широты\долготы довольно точно переводится в метры), а для больших там по идее можно получить относительно простую формулу - долгота и широта ведь по сути просто сферические координаты с постоянным радиусом

Comment: Для начала, чисто программистский трюк: можно подсчитать расстояния до объекта как числа, запомнить их, и сортировать по ним. Таким образом, у вас будет `N` вычислений расстояния, а не `N Log N`, что уже ускорит вычисления.

Comment: @VladD, добавил в ответ изменённую версию. Очевидно, много лучше. Теперь я точно не знаю, как можно улучшить его ещё. А вы?

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich: Вроде ничего не улучшается. Однако ваш код не реэнтерабельный и не потокобезопасный. Может быть, сделать [вот так](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14592764/276994)? (Хотя, не уверен, что это лучше с т. зр. производительности.)

Comment: Мне пришлось удалить один из своих комментариев, чтобы получилось написать этот))

@VladD, и опять вы правы - так, безусловно, лучше. И это точно лучше с точки зрения производительности (я проверил). 

По поводу потокобезопасности - конкретно для данного кода (и контекста, в которым он используется) это не требуется.

А вот по поводу не-реэнтрабельности можно подробнее? (хотя не знаю, как дальше с комментариями будет получаться).

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich: Ну, если чисто теоретически код сортировки будет вызывать сортировку того же массива с другими параметрами, тогда поле `precalculatedDistanceToLocation` было бы затёрто. Это в вашем случае, кажется, невозможно, но иногда такие проблемы встречаются.

Или если один элемент будет принадлежать нескольким спискам, которые будут «одновременно» сортироваться.

(С другой стороны, семантически нехорошо добавлять в `CLLocation` поле, нужное лишь на момент сортировки, но это уже красивость.)

Comment: Удалил ещё один свой комментарий и отвечаю: теперь понял, что вы имели в виду под "реэнтрабельностью" - да, здесь таких проблем не должно быть. Про "семантическую нехорошесть" я с вами согласен, но как сделать это по-другому без спуска на уровень С (структуры) я не знаю. Спасибо вам за внимание и комментарии - очень ценно!

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich: Пожалуйста!

---
Ещё одна идея: создаём массив структур типа `{ double distance, int originalIndex }` (расстояние, индекс в начальном массиве), сортируем его по `distance`, создаём новый `NSArray *`, и копируем данные из исходного массива по новым индексам. Так можно избежать дополнительного поля. [Опять-таки, если игра стоит свеч.]

Comment: @VladD, в моём случае игра точно стоит свеч - 30 минут назад я сделал ровно то, что вы только что предложили, и это очень заметно увеличивает производительность (исчез оверхед от инициализации Objective-C объектов). Так что, честь имею ! ;)

Ещё раз спасибо за участие!

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich: Примерно так: http://ideone.com/ZGAqdk Реализовал на неидиоматическом C# (идиоматический подход — через LINQ), надеюсь, переведётся легко на Objective C.

---
Всегда рад!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишу редко, но много и, надеюсь, метко. А что делать, раз на дворе бессрочный отпуск))

Этот топик получился своеобразным "два в одном": благодаря комментариям [[[[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd) мне удалось прояснить то, как улучшить оригинальный алгоритм сортировки массива гео-точек по отношению к данной точке (взятый когда-то без оглядки и какой-либо рефлексии с просторов StackOverflow - тот, что описан первым в вопросе), и как мне кажется всё получилось более, чем удачно - см. комментарии и отрывок кода в конце вопроса.

А вот ответ на оригинальный вопрос:

В топике параллельно открытом на SO некто @Taum прислал решение, которое с моими небольшими правками и оптимизациями мне подошло, как достойная альтернатива `-[CLLocation distanceFromLocation:]` и `MKMetersBeetweenMapPoints`. Вот текущие варианты обеих функций (расстояние и квадрат расстояния):

```
static inline CLLocationDistance SquaredGeodesicDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2D a, CLLocationCoordinate2D b) {
    static const CLLocationDistance EarthRadiusInMetersSquared = 40612548751652.179688;
    static const double DegreeesToRad = 0.017453292519943295769236907684886;

    CLLocationDegrees dtheta = (a.latitude - b.latitude) * DegreeesToRad;
    CLLocationDegrees dlambda = (a.longitude - b.longitude) * DegreeesToRad;
    CLLocationDegrees mean_t = (a.latitude + b.latitude) * DegreeesToRad / 2.0;
    CLLocationDegrees cos_meant = cos(mean_t);

    return EarthRadiusInMetersSquared * (dtheta * dtheta + cos_meant * cos_meant * dlambda * dlambda);
}

static inline CLLocationDistance GeodesicDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2D a, CLLocationCoordinate2D b) {
    static const CLLocationDistance EarthRadiusInMeters = 6372797.560856;
    static const double DegreeesToRad = 0.017453292519943295769236907684886;

    CLLocationDegrees dtheta = (a.latitude - b.latitude) * DegreeesToRad;
    CLLocationDegrees dlambda = (a.longitude - b.longitude) * DegreeesToRad;
    CLLocationDegrees mean_t = (a.latitude + b.latitude) * DegreeesToRad / 2.0;
    CLLocationDegrees cos_meant = cos(mean_t);

    return EarthRadiusInMeters * sqrt(dtheta * dtheta + cos_meant * cos_meant * dlambda * dlambda);
}
```

Безусловное достойнство этого метода - это то, что он работает *заметно* быстрее, чем оба метода Apple API: -[CLLocation distanceFromLocation:] и MKMetersBeetweenMapPoints (к слову сказать, попутно я выяснил, что в свою очередь сравнивая их между собой: MKMetersBeetweenMapPoints - работает значительно медленнее, чем distanceFromLocation: - откуда вывод, что для дорогих вычислений лучше оставаться в пространстве географических координат lat/lng (CLLocationDegrees) и избегать переходов к MKMapPoints).

Кроме того, в данной реализации этого метода доступна его "квадратичная версия", которая позволяет сэкономить на вычислениях вроде "есть точка и набор точек - к какой точке из этого набора данная точка ближе всего" - так как при сравнении расстояний достаточно сравнивать их квадраты.

Небольшой недостаток этого метода - это то, что он работает с небольшой погрешностью по сравнению с методами Apple API, но для той области, где я собираюсь его использовать (см. ниже) это не важно.

К сожалению, у меня нет времени проникнуть в суть математики, которая стоит за этим методом и за аналогичными методами в Википедии - поэтому единственное, что я пока что могу предположить по поводу данной реализации - это то, что она немного более грубая по сравнению с тем, что делают Apple API - отсюда скорость (хорошо!) и одновременно погрешность (плохо, но не критично).

---

Теперь добавлю контекста для этого вопроса: я экспериментирую с несколькими алгоритмами класстеризации гео-точек на карте - сравниваю как работают те, которые уже есть на Github, и те, которые я попробовал написать сам -

Например, в алгоритме K-means операция "найти ближайшую точку из набора точек до данной точки" является ключевой и поэтому от любой даже самой небольшой оптимизации подсчёта расстояния между точками (или квадрата этого расстояния) алгоритм начинает хорошо выигрывать.

Я хотел задать на ХК вопрос про такие алгоритмы (ключевые слова: кластеризация, K-Means, K-деревья, Quad-деревья, ...), но как-то всё не соображу, как бы это грамотно сформулировать, чтобы получить полезный результат (Исследование?).

---

Отмечу, что оба решения прекрасно совмещаются и отлично подходят для задач, когда нужна скорость.

---

Как всегда отмечаю, что буду рад любым комментариям/замечаниям/возражениям/недоумениям/злобнымнападкам по любым вопросам, заявленным в топике.

Да, и ещё раз спасибо за помощь, [[[[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd)!

Comment: Станислав, спасибо за код!

У меня только один вопрос.

> Кроме того, в данной реализации этого метода доступна его "квадратичная версия", которая позволяет сэкономить на вычислениях вроде "есть точка и набор точек - к какой точке из этого набора данная точка ближе всего" - так как при сравнении расстояний достаточно сравнивать их квадраты.

Не знаком с этой теорией. Почему для сравнения дистанций между точками нужно использовать квадраты, а не просто сравнивать получаемые дистанции и получать минимальную?

Comment: Я полагаю, теория скрывается в простом математическом неравенстве: для неотрицательных чисел (расстояния всегда >= 0) будет верно: что если a > b, то и квадрат a больше квадрата b, обратное при этом тоже верно.

    (a >= b) <=> (pow(a, 2) >= pow(b, 2))

Comment: > Почему для сравнения дистанций между точками нужно использовать квадраты, а не просто сравнивать получаемые дистанции и получать минимальную?

Здесь правильнее будет сказать не "нужно", а "лучше", потому что если Вас интересуют не конкретные дистанции, а отношения между ними, то быстрее сравнивать квадраты, так как для каждого данного расстояния происходит экономия: минус одно вычисление квадратного корня.

Я понятно объяснил?